# Selecting an item from a list rendered using a partial view per item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

I have a view model with a list of items. These items are rendered using a partial view within a for loop.

I want to be able to click on some text within the partial view and post back to the controller the item **and all properties** that I clicked on.

I can't simply pass an Id as once I've passed the item to the view I cannot look it up again.

What options do I have to do this?

Comment: Clarify pls, you want to pass item from list to another controller?

Comment: Why do you want to pass it to the same controller?

Comment: I'm new to MVC and thought that was typical. The work flow is (all with same controller): 1) Look up something from a DB. 2) Get a list of other things from web service. 3) Choose one of those things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I see. I'd implement this this in another way.
1st controller - to list items,
2nd controller - to manipulate items
jQuery for UI.
Client side selecting, editing - on jQuery,
Save button goes to 2nd controller. Which internally may cause refresh of list.
Refreshing items to 1st.
Also some Ajax to make client work more convenient. It seems to be perfect match.